# Configuring Azure DevOps Self-Hosted Agent to Run in Docker as a Non-Root User: Permission Issues

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-container-instances, rootless

I am working on setting up an Azure DevOps pipelines agent within an Azure Container Instance. I have been advised that running the Docker instance with root privileges can pose a security risk. Therefore, I am attempting to configure the Docker instance to run as a non-root user.

Following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops), I have created a self-hosted agent. Here is the Dockerfile I am using:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV NODE_MAJOR=18

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get upgrade -y && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  apt-transport-https=2.0.9 \
  ca-certificates=20230311ubuntu0.20.04.1 \
  curl=7.68.0-1ubuntu2.19 \
  gpg=2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 \
  gnupg=2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2 \
  lsb-release=11.1.0ubuntu2 \
  software-properties-common=0.99.9.12 \
  zip=3.0-11build1 \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg && \
  echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list


RUN mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings && \
  curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg && \
  echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  apt-utils=2.0.9 \
  git=1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.11 \
  iputils-ping=3:20190709-3 \
  jq=1.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 \
  terraform=1.5.7-1 \
  nodejs=18.18.0-1nodesource1 \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN npm install --global yarn@^1.x.x

RUN curl -fsSL https://download.red-gate.com/maven/release/org/flywaydb/enterprise/flyway-commandline/9.17.0/flyway-commandline-9.17.0-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar -xvz && \
  ln -s "$(pwd)/flyway-9.17.0/flyway" /usr/local/bin

RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash

ENV TARGETARCH=linux-x64

WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "./start.sh" ]

HEALTHCHECK --interval=1m --timeout=10s --start-period=5s --retries=3 \
  CMD pgrep -F /var/run/azp_agent.pid || exit 1
```

When I try to add a non-root user, I encounter build errors due to permission issues with the apt-get command. Moreover, running the container in rootless mode seems to cause [additional issues](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/4297).

I am seeking help with the following:

1. How can I modify the Dockerfile to avoid permission denied errors when installing packages as a non-root user?
2. Are there known solutions or workarounds for the issues encountered when running the container in rootless mode?

I tried doing

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash nonroot
USER nonroot
```

But on `docker build` I get:

```
 => ERROR [ 3/12] RUN apt-get update &&   apt-get upgrade -y &&   apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends   apt-transport-https=2.0.9   ca-certificates=20230311ubuntu0.20.04.1   curl=7.68.0-1ubuntu2.19   gpg=2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2   gnupg=2  0.4s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 > [ 3/12] RUN apt-get update &&   apt-get upgrade -y &&   apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends   apt-transport-https=2.0.9   ca-certificates=20230311ubuntu0.20.04.1   curl=7.68.0-1ubuntu2.19   gpg=2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2   gnupg=2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2   lsb-release=11.1.0ubuntu2   software-properties-common=0.99.9.12   zip=3.0-11build1   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
#6 0.318 Reading package lists...
#6 0.422 E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -o pipefail -c apt-get update &&   apt-get upgrade -y &&   apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends   apt-transport-https=2.0.9   ca-certificates=20230311ubuntu0.20.04.1   curl=7.68.0-1ubuntu2.19   gpg=2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2   gnupg=2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2   lsb-release=11.1.0ubuntu2   software-properties-common=0.99.9.12   zip=3.0-11build1   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 100
```

I can't use `sudo` for the same security concenrns of course.